# WINE glitches textures AMD

Tags: graphics, wine, amd-graphics

I have a ASUS VivoBook 15 with a AMD Radeon Vega Graphics GPU and I cannot run any game without having the same glitches. I have used WINE for the last 10 years and I've never seen anything like it. I tried searching on different websites for someone with the same problem but couldn't find anything. I have a feeling it has to do with the driver but I'm really not sure. Anyway this is my `glxinfo`:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, 
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_libglvnd, GLX_EXT_no_config_context, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, 
    GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_no_error, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, 
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_buffer_age, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: X.Org (0x1002)
    Device: AMD RAVEN2 (DRM 3.35.0, 5.4.0-56-generic, LLVM 10.0.0) (0x15d8)
    Version: 20.0.8
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 2048MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 4.6
    Max compat profile version: 4.6
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
Memory info (GL_ATI_meminfo):
    VBO free memory - total: 1849 MB, largest block: 1849 MB
    VBO free aux. memory - total: 2839 MB, largest block: 2839 MB
    Texture free memory - total: 1849 MB, largest block: 1849 MB
    Texture free aux. memory - total: 2839 MB, largest block: 2839 MB
    Renderbuffer free memory - total: 1849 MB, largest block: 1849 MB
    Renderbuffer free aux. memory - total: 2839 MB, largest block: 2839 MB
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):
    Dedicated video memory: 2048 MB
    Total available memory: 5120 MB
    Currently available dedicated video memory: 1849 MB
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD RAVEN2 (DRM 3.35.0, 5.4.0-56-generic, LLVM 10.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
    GL_AMD_conservative_depth, GL_AMD_depth_clamp_separate, 
    GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, GL_AMD_framebuffer_multisample_advanced, 
    GL_AMD_gpu_shader_int64, GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, 
    GL_AMD_performance_monitor, GL_AMD_pinned_memory, 
    GL_AMD_query_buffer_object, GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, 
    GL_AMD_shader_stencil_export, GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, 
    GL_AMD_texture_texture4, GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer, 
    GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, 
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_2_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays, GL_ARB_base_instance, 
    GL_ARB_bindless_texture, GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, 
    GL_ARB_buffer_storage, GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_clear_texture, 
    GL_ARB_clip_control, GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, 
    GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, GL_ARB_compute_shader, 
    GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, 
    GL_ARB_conservative_depth, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_copy_image, 
    GL_ARB_cull_distance, GL_ARB_debug_output, GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, 
    GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_derivative_control, GL_ARB_direct_state_access, 
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, 
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_draw_indirect, 
    GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GL_ARB_get_program_binary, GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image, GL_ARB_gl_spirv, 
    GL_ARB_gpu_shader5, GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64, GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_indirect_parameters, GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, 
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query, GL_ARB_internalformat_query2, 
    GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata, GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind, GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, GL_ARB_parallel_shader_compile, 
    GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_polygon_offset_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_program_interface_query, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_query_buffer_object, GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior, 
    GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sample_shading, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, 
    GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, 
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops, 
    GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters, GL_ARB_shader_ballot, 
    GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, GL_ARB_shader_clock, 
    GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters, GL_ARB_shader_group_vote, 
    GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store, GL_ARB_shader_image_size, 
    GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_precision, 
    GL_ARB_shader_stencil_export, GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_shader_subroutine, GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples, 
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_ARB_shader_viewport_layer_array, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack, GL_ARB_shading_language_include, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, GL_ARB_spirv_extensions, 
    GL_ARB_stencil_texturing, GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_tessellation_shader, 
    GL_ARB_texture_barrier, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc, GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array, GL_ARB_texture_filter_anisotropic, 
    GL_ARB_texture_float, GL_ARB_texture_gather, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge, GL_ARB_texture_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_query_levels, 
    GL_ARB_texture_query_lod, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, GL_ARB_texture_stencil8, 
    GL_ARB_texture_storage, GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, GL_ARB_texture_view, GL_ARB_timer_query, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback2, GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback_overflow_query, GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit, GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, 
    GL_ARB_viewport_array, GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_ATI_meminfo, 
    GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, 
    GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage, GL_EXT_EGL_sync, GL_EXT_abgr, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_depth_bounds_test, 
    GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_memory_object, 
    GL_EXT_memory_object_fd, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_packed_float, 
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_semaphore, GL_EXT_semaphore_fd, 
    GL_EXT_shader_image_load_formatted, GL_EXT_shader_image_load_store, 
    GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical, 
    GL_EXT_texture_array, GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_integer, 
    GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, 
    GL_EXT_texture_snorm, GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query, 
    GL_EXT_transform_feedback, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_attrib_64bit, GL_EXT_window_rectangles, 
    GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced, 
    GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_KHR_debug, GL_KHR_no_error, 
    GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile, GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior, 
    GL_KHR_robustness, GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr, 
    GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d, GL_MESA_framebuffer_flip_y, 
    GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions, 
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_NV_texture_barrier, GL_NV_vdpau_interop, GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_S3_s3tc

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_AMD_conservative_depth, GL_AMD_depth_clamp_separate, 
    GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, GL_AMD_framebuffer_multisample_advanced, 
    GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect, GL_AMD_performance_monitor, 
    GL_AMD_pinned_memory, GL_AMD_query_buffer_object, 
    GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, GL_AMD_shader_stencil_export, 
    GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, GL_AMD_texture_texture4, 
    GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer, GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index, 
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, 
    GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays, GL_ARB_base_instance, GL_ARB_bindless_texture, 
    GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_buffer_storage, 
    GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_clear_texture, GL_ARB_clip_control, 
    GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, GL_ARB_compute_shader, 
    GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size, GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, 
    GL_ARB_conservative_depth, GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_copy_image, 
    GL_ARB_cull_distance, GL_ARB_debug_output, GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, 
    GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_derivative_control, 
    GL_ARB_direct_state_access, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GL_ARB_get_program_binary, GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image, GL_ARB_gl_spirv, 
    GL_ARB_gpu_shader5, GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64, GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_indirect_parameters, GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, 
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query, GL_ARB_internalformat_query2, 
    GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata, GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind, GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect, 
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, GL_ARB_parallel_shader_compile, 
    GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_polygon_offset_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_program_interface_query, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_query_buffer_object, GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior, 
    GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sample_shading, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, 
    GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, 
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops, 
    GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters, GL_ARB_shader_ballot, 
    GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, GL_ARB_shader_clock, 
    GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters, GL_ARB_shader_group_vote, 
    GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store, GL_ARB_shader_image_size, 
    GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_precision, 
    GL_ARB_shader_stencil_export, GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_shader_subroutine, GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples, 
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_ARB_shader_viewport_layer_array, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_100, GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_include, GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, 
    GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_spirv_extensions, GL_ARB_stencil_texturing, 
    GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_tessellation_shader, GL_ARB_texture_barrier, 
    GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array, GL_ARB_texture_env_add, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_filter_anisotropic, 
    GL_ARB_texture_float, GL_ARB_texture_gather, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_ARB_texture_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, 
    GL_ARB_texture_query_levels, GL_ARB_texture_query_lod, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, 
    GL_ARB_texture_stencil8, GL_ARB_texture_storage, 
    GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, 
    GL_ARB_texture_view, GL_ARB_timer_query, GL_ARB_transform_feedback2, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback_overflow_query, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, 
    GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, 
    GL_ARB_viewport_array, GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, 
    GL_ATI_draw_buffers, GL_ATI_fragment_shader, GL_ATI_meminfo, 
    GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_ATI_texture_compression_3dc, 
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_float, 
    GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage, GL_EXT_EGL_sync, 
    GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, 
    GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_depth_bounds_test, GL_EXT_direct_state_access, 
    GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, 
    GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_gpu_shader4, GL_EXT_memory_object, GL_EXT_memory_object_fd, 
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_point_parameters, GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color, 
    GL_EXT_semaphore, GL_EXT_semaphore_fd, GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, 
    GL_EXT_shader_image_load_formatted, GL_EXT_shader_image_load_store, 
    GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical, 
    GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, 
    GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture, GL_EXT_texture3D, 
    GL_EXT_texture_array, GL_EXT_texture_buffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_add, GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, 
    GL_EXT_texture_integer, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, 
    GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, 
    GL_EXT_texture_snorm, GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query, 
    GL_EXT_transform_feedback, GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_attrib_64bit, GL_EXT_window_rectangles, 
    GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced, GL_KHR_context_flush_control, 
    GL_KHR_debug, GL_KHR_no_error, GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile, 
    GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior, GL_KHR_robustness, 
    GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr, 
    GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d, GL_MESA_framebuffer_flip_y, 
    GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions, 
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, 
    GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_NV_fog_distance, GL_NV_light_max_exponent, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_NV_primitive_restart, GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_barrier, 
    GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_NV_vdpau_interop, 
    GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_OES_read_format, GL_S3_s3tc, 
    GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
    GL_AMD_framebuffer_multisample_advanced, GL_AMD_performance_monitor, 
    GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, 
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, GL_APPLE_texture_max_level, 
    GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage, GL_EXT_base_instance, 
    GL_EXT_blend_func_extended, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_buffer_storage, 
    GL_EXT_clip_control, GL_EXT_clip_cull_distance, GL_EXT_color_buffer_float, 
    GL_EXT_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_sub_texture, GL_EXT_copy_image, 
    GL_EXT_depth_clamp, GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer, 
    GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query, GL_EXT_draw_buffers, 
    GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed, GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex, 
    GL_EXT_float_blend, GL_EXT_frag_depth, GL_EXT_geometry_point_size, 
    GL_EXT_geometry_shader, GL_EXT_gpu_shader5, GL_EXT_map_buffer_range, 
    GL_EXT_memory_object, GL_EXT_memory_object_fd, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, 
    GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean, GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box, GL_EXT_read_format_bgra, 
    GL_EXT_render_snorm, GL_EXT_robustness, GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control, 
    GL_EXT_semaphore, GL_EXT_semaphore_fd, GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, 
    GL_EXT_shader_implicit_conversions, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, 
    GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks, GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical, 
    GL_EXT_tessellation_point_size, GL_EXT_tessellation_shader, 
    GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_buffer, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_bptc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc_srgb, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888, 
    GL_EXT_texture_norm16, GL_EXT_texture_query_lod, GL_EXT_texture_rg, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, 
    GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV, GL_EXT_texture_view, 
    GL_EXT_unpack_subimage, GL_EXT_window_rectangles, 
    GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced, GL_KHR_context_flush_control, 
    GL_KHR_debug, GL_KHR_no_error, GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile, 
    GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior, GL_KHR_robustness, 
    GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr, 
    GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d, GL_MESA_framebuffer_flip_y, 
    GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_NV_draw_buffers, GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments, GL_NV_image_formats, 
    GL_NV_read_buffer, GL_NV_read_depth, GL_NV_read_depth_stencil, 
    GL_NV_read_stencil, GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_OES_EGL_image_external, 
    GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3, GL_OES_EGL_sync, 
    GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture, GL_OES_copy_image, GL_OES_depth24, 
    GL_OES_depth_texture, GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_OES_draw_buffers_indexed, GL_OES_draw_elements_base_vertex, 
    GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap, 
    GL_OES_geometry_point_size, GL_OES_geometry_shader, 
    GL_OES_get_program_binary, GL_OES_gpu_shader5, GL_OES_mapbuffer, 
    GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil, GL_OES_primitive_bounding_box, 
    GL_OES_required_internalformat, GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8, GL_OES_sample_shading, 
    GL_OES_sample_variables, GL_OES_shader_image_atomic, 
    GL_OES_shader_io_blocks, GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation, 
    GL_OES_standard_derivatives, GL_OES_stencil8, GL_OES_surfaceless_context, 
    GL_OES_tessellation_point_size, GL_OES_tessellation_shader, 
    GL_OES_texture_3D, GL_OES_texture_border_clamp, GL_OES_texture_buffer, 
    GL_OES_texture_cube_map_array, GL_OES_texture_float, 
    GL_OES_texture_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_half_float, 
    GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_npot, 
    GL_OES_texture_stencil8, GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array, 
    GL_OES_texture_view, GL_OES_vertex_array_object, GL_OES_vertex_half_float, 
    GL_OES_viewport_array
```

And these are screenshots of S.T.A.L.K.E.R: Clear Sky. This has been installed following the PlayOnLinux installer along some other extra components (note that the visuals are always the same, the cursor starts like spinning and the textures don't fully load; and this is independent of the game I'm running)
[image: Main menu STALKER CLEAR SKY]
[image: Gameplay STALKER]